# How to convert data into a pdf file?

Tags: iphone, ipad, pdf-generation

How would I go about converting my data into a pdf on an ipad or iphone?

Comment: thanks oded making my language correction :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone PDF creation library or functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229414/iphone-pdf-creation-library-or-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370292/create-pdf-inapp-ipad):

> Try this one:
>
> http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/10989-pdf-creation-tutorial.html

or

Apple: [Creating a PDF file](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html)

Comment: @kiran kumar, Do those links help answer your question?